# How to get hellstone quickly?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I was playing Terraria on iOS and I accidentally deleted a world and lost all my hellstone ingots. Is there a way to get easy hellstone because I already have obsidian, but the time consuming task of collecting it is driving me insane!

Answer (score 3):

Craft a lot of Obsidian Skin Potions and go ahead! You need fireblossom, waterleaf, obsidian and water bottle to craft them.They work 4 mins and each one can get you some stacks of hellstone. Hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

Make an inside an obsidian head and equip it. It will let you be immune to fire blocks. Then just find a safe place to mine the hellstone because once you mine it, it will let out lava. An easy way is to mine over it with something in between you and the he llstone then mine it. I got 93 hellstone doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you know how you can pick up blocks if they're close even though they're behind walls or platforms? Put that advantage to good use. Separate yourself between the Hellstone with Ashblocks around it. Also, get a Imp Staff after you get enough Hellstone so it can guard you while you mine the other Hellstones. You could try to dig a "drain" to dump the lava out so you can safely get the Hellstone blocks if you want. Get a friend to help you out. You may have to share(or not if they're OP) the loot but it makes things go faster.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest using a lava charm try making some storage for your hellstone by putting stacks in a chest oh and don’t forget obsidian skull and obsidian sheild could be useful. I got unlimited bars from this